# Using Gcloud with Vagrant

Tags: docker, redis, vagrant, gcloud

I have ssh-connected to my vagrant minion, installed the Google Cloud SDK, authenticated and when I run:

```
gcloud docker pull redis
```

I get:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): No JSON object could be decoded
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Do you mind [filing an issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list) about this (please be sure to include the log file, or at least the stack trace? `gcloud` should be giving you a better error in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

run:

```
docker login
```

the json file in question is now at:

```
/root/.docker/config.json
```